# How to customize UITextField to look like table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to create login view for my iOS App something like this table view :

[image]

Should I have to make a Custom Background Image or is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: If I'm not wrong those are tableview cells with textfields(no border) as subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways
1.you can go for custom back ground and then add two textfields exactly where you want them to be then set the border style to none.
2.You can choose tableview then you can add textfields to it.

Whatever the way is you need to scroll or animate  the view when keyboard pops up for better look.If you use the first 1 you should add scroll view,for the second 1 no need to add scrool because table view  is a child of scroll view.